# Display file from Firebase Storage in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

I couldn't find anything on this subject so here's my question :

How to display a file from Firebase Storage in Flutter ?

So far, here's my function :

```
  PlatformFile? pickedFile;

  Future uploadDoc() async {
    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      allowMultiple: false,
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['pdf', 'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'],
    );
    if (result != null) {
      setState(() {
        pickedFile = result.files.first;
      });
    } else {
      return null;
    }

    if (pickedFile != null) {
      final destination = 'files/';
      final file = File(pickedFile!.path!);
      Reference ref =
          FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(destination).child(pickedFile!.name);

      await ref.putFile(file);

      String url = await ref.getDownloadURL();

      print('$url is UPLOADED');
    
    }
  }
```

At this point, the file is uploaded in storage. I can get its URL and display its name using a FutureBuilder :

```
 futureFiles = storage.ref('files/').listAll();

  FutureBuilder<ListResult>(
        future: futureFiles,
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Something went wrong');
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ||
              !snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              ),
            );
          } else {
            final files = snapshot.data!.items;
            return ListView.builder( 
                    itemCount: files.length,
                    itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                      final file = files[index];
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(file.name),
                        trailing: Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.launch),
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              onPressed: () {
                              // FUNCTION TO DISPLAY THE FILE
                              },
                            ),
                      );
                    })),
              ],
            );
          }
        },
      ),
```

The uploaded files's name are listed, but how can I display the file itself ?

I think the right way should be to access the file's URL, but I don't know how. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

the `getDownloadURL()` will get you a network url of that image, in your example, you're already saving it as :

```
String url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
```

you can simply assign that URL to an `Image.network()` widget to show it:

```
Image.network(url), // will show the image
```

Comment: Good call ! Only small problem though : if I restart the app, the url variable is reset as well and becomes null. How can I get the URL and keep it no matter if I restart or not ?

Comment: for this, you should think about what approach you gonna follow, you can set an alternative placeholder URL until you get the original URLs, or you can catch it the memory using as example the CachedNetworkImage package

Comment: but what I recommend is to make a `Future` method that gets the `getDownloadURL()` of your image, then combine it with a `FutureBuilder` to get it, then show it in a `Image.network()`

Comment: But why would I use this way if the url I need is already store in storage ?
I need a way to get the URL like this : ```Image.network(file.url)``` just like I used ```file.name``` in my FutureBuilder.

Comment: You have to store the url somewhere...eg. shared prefs, a firebase database, a local database such as hive...there are many ways to save the url for use next time the app opens. In all cases though, I would suggest you use CachedNetworkImage to display it. That will ensure the image is downloaded only when it is not available on the device.

Comment: Thank you @GrahamD you pointed an obvious fact that I only realised after I read your comment. I stored the URL in Firestore and now I'm able to use it ! :)